# Optimization of square matrix multiplied with another matrix to have the final result a unitary matrix

Tags: matrix, optimization, linear-algebra, convex-optimization

I have a square matrix $D$ whose size is $m \times m$ multiplied with another  $m \times m$ square matrix $C$, I need to optimize the matrix $C$ to have a unitary matrix $DC$. I mean optimize the matrix $C$ such as $DC$ is a unitary matrix.

In my opinion, that can be formulated as below:

\begin{align}
\min_C \|DC - Y\|^2_F&& \text{s.t.}&&(DC)(DC)^H = I_m
\end{align}

where $\|\cdot\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm operator and $Y$ is any unitary matrix.

So, I don't know if we can deal with the above equality as a variant of the Procrustes problem or that's not possible.  Is it possible to optimize that above equation based on $C$ following my way ? or is there another way we can set the matrix $C$ to have $(DC)(DC)^H = I_m$  ?

NB: All the matrices are real and $det(D) = 0$.

Comment: If $det(D) \ne 0$ D is invertible and you can just use $C = D^{-1}$. Than you have $D \cdot C = I$ and $I$ sure is unitary.

Comment: @Hilmar What's about if $det(D) = 0$ ?

Comment: Then your problem isn't solvable: If $det(D) = 0$ then $det(D\cdot C) = 0$. That means the product can't be unitary regardless of  C. I'll turn this into an answer, since I think that's all there is to it

Comment: Hey Fatima, I think Hilmar's answer is factually correctly answering your question as stated, but I'm not sure it's what you meant. Is it possible $\text{mean}_C$ is supposed to mean $\min\limits_C$?

Comment: and when you say "$Y$ is any unitary matrix", does it mean *you* can freely choose $Y$ as long as it's unitary, or is $Y$ externally given?

Comment: @MarcusMüller,   Thank you. I have edited it in the question.

Answer (score 4):

Could it be that you are indeed looking for the **closest** orthogonal matrix $Y$? Then, there is a solution which involves computing the square root of $ D^TD$ . If $E=(D^TD)^{1/2}$ were invertible, the solution would be its inverse. Yet, it is not invertible here.   Then, there is a trick. If I remember well, you have to perform an eigenvalue/eigenvector decomposition of $E$, replace the null eigenvalues by $1$, you then get a novel matrix $E^*$ which is invertible, and its inverse is the (unique) solution.

If what I wrote is correct enough, I might come back with details. Meanwhile, you can look at:

- [Finding the Nearest Orthonormal Matrix](http://people.csail.mit.edu/bkph/articles/Nearest_Orthonormal_Matrix.pdf)
- [The Nearest Orthogonal or Unitary Matrix](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ewkahan/Math128/NearestQ.pdf)

Comment: Yes Exactly, I am looking for the closest unitary matrix $Y$. The matrix $E$ in my case is not invertible. Could you please explain how to solve that matrix $E$? ... Thanks again

Comment: Yes, please let me some time. Did you check the two links, did you understand the basic steps?

Comment: I am reading it, but I couldn't get its exact idea. I try to implement when I understand from it in Matlab but something wrong is happening. Please, your explanation will be really appreciated.

Comment: Second, based on my understanding, $E$ might be complex matrix. However all other matrices are real. I don't know if it can be set to real or no. Anyway, awaiting for you explanation, thanks again.

Comment: Hi Duval, I would like just to remind you about this concern. thank you so much

Comment: Sure, as long as it is clear that we do this on our free time

Comment: of course, take your time, I wanted just to remind you if your forgot about it

Comment: I am still waiting for your feedback

Answer (score 2):

If D is not singular, i.e. $\operatorname*{det}(D) \ne 0$ than simply $C = D^{-1}$ will do the trick, since $D \cdot C = I$, which is obviously unitary.

If D is singular, i.e. $\operatorname*{det}(D) = 0$ than the product is also singular,  i.e. $\operatorname*{det}(D \cdot C)=0$ which means the product cannot be unitary for all possible matrices $C$.